# asp.net core websockets different between machines

Tags: .net, websocket, asp.net-core

I have the following code to support websockets on the server side:

```
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[4096*1024]);
    WebSocketReceiveResult received;
    try
    {
        received = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        continue;
    }
    //process the message
}
```

On one machine (development, IISExpress, Windows 10) it works ok (wait on ReceiveAsync until message arrives), while it works somewhat weird on staging environment (Windows Server 2012, IIS) - ReceiveAsync constantly throws `IOException` with message `Unexpected end of stream`. The socket however is still open, I can retry the call to `ReceiveAsync` and if there indeed is a message it succeeds and returns the message. Any idea how can I find out why it throws an exception when there is no message available instead of just waiting for one?

EDIT: when thinking of it I am actually not sure that the `ReceiveAsync` ever receives a message (cannot check now), but I am sure that the communication between browser and backend works so the websocket is definitely open (which I also confirmed by checking State property after getting the exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that on IIS I was using app pool with .NET CLR version set to v4.0, while it should be No Managed Code.